# function onload not working for IE7 and 8

Tags: html

My onload function is not working for IE7 and 8:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function onload()
  {
    alert("Working properly")
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The alert doesn't happen if I try to access it with IE7 or 8 but it's working properly in Mozilla.

Can anyone suggest something which works for both IE and Mozilla?

Answer (score 3):

This works only for IE.

Instead

```
function onload()  {    
       alert("Working properly") 
 }
```

try this..

```
function window.onload()  {    
       alert("Working properly") 
 }
```

**EDIT:**

Common approach for both browsers

```
function onload()  {    
  alert("Working properly") 
}    
var browserName=navigator.appName;     
if(browserName=="Microsoft Internet Explorer") 
{     
      window.onload=onload;   
} 
else 
{     
     if (document.addEventListener) 
     { 
         document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", onload, false);
     } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks it is working if found only one thing need to change function name from onload to some thing else than it work fine.

If we keep name as onload will not work for IE..

Many thanks for this again

Answer (score 0):

Use a toolkit like JQuery or Mootools, which will take care entirely of these details for you.

In JQuery, you add the link to the jquery.js, then this would look like:

```
$(function() { alert("Working properly"); });
```